# Validate array in php if all fields are blank

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, validation

I have array for uploading photos. I have to validate it for blank values.

```
 <input type="file" name="photos[]">
 <input type="file" name="photos[]">
 <input type="file" name="photos[]">
```

If a pic is uploaded in any of 3 fields, It should not throw error else if all the fields are blank, it shld throw error such as "Required at least 1 field.".

Please Note: input field photos[] are dynamically generated with jquery to upload multiple photos at a time. Please Help

Comment: Even validation in jquery or javascript will do.

Comment: what you have done for this and need js validation or in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you  to check the file upload from PHP

```
if (isset($_FILES['photos'])) {
    $photos = $_FILES['photos'];
    $proceed = false;
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        if ($photo["error"] <= 0) {
            $proceed = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$proceed) {
        echo "Please upload at least one file";
    }
}
```

or you can directly use jQuery / Javascript for this before submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Take same id for the array and call check_image() where you want to check .
it is not a complete way but this trick will do the needful. 
Hoping it will do what you need .

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photos[]">
    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photos[]">
    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photos[]">
    <script>
    function check_image()
    {
    if(document.getElementById('photo').value=='')
    {
    alert("please uplaod atleast one image");
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
    }
    </script>
```